# Virtual environment for a project that uses both python 2 and 3?

Tags: python, virtual, environment, pipenv

I'm working on a big project (mostly C/C++) that has some python stuff in it. Most of the python stuff is based on python3, but some legacy code runs on python2. Does somebody here knows about a virtual environment tool that supports multiple versions of python at the same time?
I've tried venv, virtualwnv, pyenv, pipenv with no luck. They all rely on having a single version of python on them.
I would need to be able ti specify in the virtual environment a python2 and a python3, just like I do on the system install.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use Anaconda as it enables using different python versions in different environments, which you can specify at your own.

I created a [blogpost](https://michaeljanz-data.science/further-topics/setup-python-environment-with-anaconda-git-bash-for-deep-learning-2/) about creating an environment with Anaconda, just create two different environments, one with python2.x and one with python3.x:

```
conda create -n python2env python=3.7
conda create -n python3env python=2.7
```

Comment: I guess @MichaelJanz answer covers it. But if you just want a quick and basic implementation, you could just install miniconda (https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)

It comes with python 3.8 as default but you could use same commands above.
Anaconda is huge in size, and if you are not into data science, you wouldn't need it

Answer (score 0):

Virtualenvs simply can't be shared across Python versions - not even minor versions (3.x), much less Py2 and Py3 at the same time.

For a project that has bits in Python 2 and Python 3, you will need two virtualenvs, e.g.

```
python2 -m virtualenv py2_venv
python3 -m virtualenv py3_venv
```

or however you like.